# Flask admin only display certain objects in model on load

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a mysql table that contains a bunch of laptops. I want to be able use Flask Admin ModelView to split the table into 2 categories Mac and WIN. Is there a way form on load to query the table for those MAC (ex) laptops and display them on the table? I do understand I'll need to separate model views for Mac and WIN just that I don't know how to query and load the data on the page load with the table

Answer (score 0):

after digging around all I had to add to my model view are these methods:

```
def get_query(self):
    return super(LaptopModelView, self).get_query().filter(
        Laptops.system == "pc"
    )

def get_count_query(self):
    return super(LaptopModelView, self).get_count_query().filter(
        Laptops.system == "pc"
    )
```